# Nested validators can only be used with Member Expressions

Tags: validation, member, fluent

I am trying to use fluent validation . 
Looking to run validation against the IList items.

```
  public class ProgramDetailsValidatorForBulkEdit : ValidatorCollection<IList<ProgramDTO>>
{

    public ProgramDetailsValidatorForBulkEdit()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).SetCollectionValidator(new ProgramDetailsValidator1());

    }
}
public class ProgramDetailsValidator1 : AbstractValidator<ProgramDTO>
{
    public ProgramDetailsValidator1()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Capacity).NotNull()
            .WithMessage(String.Format(AppConstants.ValidationTemplates.RequiredField, "Capacity"));

    }
}
```

The **error** returned when calling the line is "Nested validators can only be used with Member Expressions."

```
RuleFor(x => x).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure).SetCollectionValidator(new ProgramDetailsValidator1());
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reason of error

Error message contains words "Member Expressions". The problem is in `RuleFor(x => x)`. Nested validators must be used only with lambdas which select some members of `x`, for example, with `x => x.MySubobject1`. Lambda `x => x` does not select any member of `x`.

### To validate the collection

Create object containing the list:

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You can use generics to create 1 universal object and validator for it for all lists.

```cs
public class MyObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject>
{
    public MyObjectValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Items)  // will work, because it is not "x => x"
            .SetCollectionValidator(new ItemValidator());
    }
}
```

### To validate an object

Use lambdas pointing to members to validate inner objects and use inheritance from your object's validator to validate the root `x`.

```cs
public class MySimpleObject { ... }

public class MyCompositeObject : MySimpleObject
{
    public MyType1 MySubobject1 { get; set; }
    public MyType2 MySubobject2 { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class MySimpleObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MySimpleObject>
{
    public MySimpleObjectValidator()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyCompositeObjectValidator : MySimpleObjectValidator 
{
    public MyCompositeObjectValidator () : base()  // Call base validator to implement rules for "x => x" written in MySimpleObjectValidator!
    {
        // Rules for SUBobjects will work
        RuleFor(x => x.MySubobject1)
                .SetValidator(new MyType1Validator())
                .WithName("Subobject1's errors group");

        RuleFor(x => x.MySubobject2)
                .SetValidator(new MyType2Validator())
                .WithName("Subobject2's errors group");
    }   
}
```